# GParted not opening

Tags: partitioning, gparted, unallocated

I am a newbie in Ubuntu.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1, dual booted with Windows 8.

I have some unallocated space on my hard disk which I want to use in Ubuntu. I heard Gparted is the best tool for this.

I ran the command `gksudo gparted` on the terminal, I got a pop-up asking for my password. Upon entering the password, the window closes and nothing happens. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You need to install gparted first. Then you will see it in Dash.

Comment: To install try: `sudo apt-get install gparted`.  Also, next time you try, do so using only `sudo gparted` so if there are any error messages on the terminal you can report them.

Comment: Open the dash with the <kbd>super</kbd> key and type gparted. It should work.